# PHP time zone not staying consistant

Tags: php, timezone, simple-machines-forum

I help run a forum using the Simple Machines Forum framework.  The forum's time settings are correct--all the posts show up as the correct time for the poster's time zone.

We installed a plugin (SMF calls it a package) for a little online-user chat function.  The timestamp on this chat program is not correct--it doesn't match the forum.  I am based in Michigan (GMT-4), but it always shows four hours later than my current time (GMT 0).

I have done a huge amount of research on this and here is what I've got.

**Have you changed the php.ini file in the root directory's date.timezone setting?**

Yes.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

**Have you modified the index.php file in the plugin directory's date_default_timezone_set setting?**

Yes.

```
if (!ini_get('date.timezone'))
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

I'm not terribly well versed in PHP, so I might have added a space or missed a semicolon or something that I just wouldn't know to notice.  One thing I DID notice is that the timestamps of **previous** messages (before a hard refresh) in the chat log will adjust the time if I change the timezone.  Current messages however still stick at GMT0, so I wonder if something *somewhere* is overriding the timezone I'm trying to set for it.

I'm at an absolute loss for what to check next.  I'm out of my depth, as it is.

Comment: Must be something in this "plugin" changing your date. Do you have a link to the code?

Comment: Hi @miken32, here's the link to the mod itself:  [SA Chat](http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=2534)


If you want to, you could download the mod and just crack open the ZIP file to take a look at the code.

Comment: agree with the others look for this "date_default_timezone_set" inside the plugin

Comment: Just did a quick grep over the contents for `ini_set`, `timezone`, and `tz` with no luck. I'd work with the guy who wrote it, as he's probably more familiar with how it works.

Comment: @Gert, I did.  As I mentioned in my original post, I have already changed that, but it's still not working.

Comment: @miken32 Yeah, he hasn't been responsive on the feedback section for a while.  That's why I thought I'd try here.  =P